# How can I go forward with this image processing task?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I am totally new to Image processing. I just started my Master thesis in the area of Computer vision and Machine learning. My background is Informatics. Now, my first task is to register the images of some fishes(Image registration) as they come out of water. I have got stream of images and I want to come up with a model of the fish by aligning the temporally different images of a fish. As, I can understand, I will have to fist of all remove the background and water from the images to work on just fishes, am I right?

Can anyone give me a brief idea of how I should go forward or the things I should read first before I can understand the things. For example, should I read the basics of Image Processing, Feature detection, Image segmentation....? and regarding the programming language I can use - one where I can find good libraries, forums, other help.

I would be really grateful, if anyone can help. Thanks.

Comment: Since this is more of an image processing (theory) question than a programming question you might be better off asking in http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Okay, will do that. Thanks. :)

Comment: I am not sure if you are using correct terms here. Usually image registration means aligning two images that contain same objects. But what you are describing sounds like fish detection in the image. As for computer vision, yes, you should study more about image processing and analysis. As far as I know, there is no shortcut for this subject. Google terms like Matlab, DIPUM, OpenCV, and so on.

Comment: @user3706505: You don't need to do any background subtraction.  What I would recommend you do is examine **keypoint detection algorithms** such as SIFT, SURF, etc.  These will find predominant features of the object of interest you want.  In other images you want to test, it will find predominant features in that too, and you can match keypoints between your query and the other images. You can also use these keypoints to align the images together.  Take a look at SIFT and SURF to start.  Also, I'm not sure what platform you're using, but OpenCV is a great place to start.